# including files with vb.net installation

Tags: vb.net

when i am building the installation file i need to be including some jpegs and i need them to be saved to a specific location

1. how do i include jpegs in the installation?
2. how do i have them be extracted to specific directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do that via Setup Project that should be added to your existing project.

After you created it, open context menu on "File system on target machine", select "Add special folder" -> "Custom folder"

Next step is to add your jpeg files.
Right click on your new folder and select "Add file".
Select all your jpegs.

Now, you need to select the location where that folder with jpegs will be
You need to open properties for that new folder and select appropriate directory for DefaultLocation property.

Keep in mind, that its good practice to store your files within the installed application. That's why the DefaultLocaiton does not allow you to just enter any custom path you want. You will have only limited list of folders, but that should be enough.

After you compile the project it will create you an installation file that will contain all your stuff