# Visual Basic did NOT include 6 .jpg files in my installation copy

Tags: vb.net

- I'm using Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2017.
- My program needs to have access to six .jpg images of the six sides of a die (d6).
- I added the files to my IDE's `bin\Debug` folder, but the compiler did NOT include those six .jpg files in my installation copy of my software.

How do I tell the compiler to include the six .jpg images in the installation file?

```
        die1 = RollD6()
        die2 = RollD6()
        'txtDie1.Text = die1
        'txtDie2.Text = die2

        picDie1.Image = Image.FromFile("die" & die1 & ".jpg")
        picDie2.Image = Image.FromFile("die" & die2 & ".jpg")

        Output("You placed a bet of " & wager.ToString("C0"))
        pot -= wager
        Output("Your pot is now " & pot.ToString("C0"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [including files with vb.net installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604187/including-files-with-vb-net-installation)

Comment: *"I added the files to my IDE's bin\Debug folder"*. Then you're wrong from the outset. Add them to your project and then configure the properties appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of loading the images from a folder, embed them in your app as resources and then just call the resource as needed.

One way:

Open the Properties for your project and navigate to the Resources tab, then add your pictures there:

[image]

Then to use it, for example if you added a "die1" pic, just:

```
picDie1.Image = My.Resources.die1
```

Comment: I downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2019.  I went to: Project/programName Properties/Resources/ Add Resource/ Add Existing File/ I chose six jpg images of the six sides of a die.  I still get an exception when I install the program and run it from the Windows Start Button.

Comment: My program threw an exception that it couldn’t find the “dieN.jpg” file, where N is an integer between 1 and 6.